# sktime import: issue with 'sktime.classification.interval_based'

Tags: python, import, time-series, classification, sktime

Can anyone help resolve this issue?

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'TimeSeriesForestClassifier' from 'sktime.classification.interval_based' 
(C:\Users\GLP\anaconda3\envs\first_tests_python_38\lib\site-packages\sktime\classification\interval_based\__init__.py)
```

Context is to import modules for multivariate time series classification with `TimeSeriesForestClassifier`

Apparently it accepts:

```
from sktime.classification.compose import TimeSeriesForestClassifier
```

but not

```
from sktime.classification.interval_based' import TimeSeriesForestClassifier
```

Comment: Hi @Daniele Baranzini, has this been resolved?

Comment: Hi @mloning, not yet...    the .compose works properly for multivatiate time series with your sktime... but method .interval_based is not ... not sure about the actual difference between .compose and .interval_based though ...

Comment: They are implemented in different ways, the one in interval_based is more efficient, the one in compose is more modular.